# SSL error message using MMQGIS and Google Geocoding API

Tags: qgis, geocoding, google, mmqgis

I have a large batch of about 9000 addresses that require geocoding. I've read most of the documentation, and have sectioned my data into chunks of 1000 to geocode using QGIS's MMQGIS Plugin. I also used my Google API key. However, it fails to run and returns this error message:

> failure connecting to maps.googleapis.com
>   url open error [ssl: certificate_verify_failed (_ssl.c:833)

I've tried reinstalling everything (the latest python, the latest QGIS, the latest MMQGIS plugin), but the same error message appears. I even shortened my dataset to 10 addresses but it still returns the same error message.

There is definitely no issue with my API key either as when I run the URL: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?sensor=false& + address + &key= + apikey , the api works.

Anyone has any idea what might be the problem?

Comment: api changes came into effect July 2018.

Comment: What is this api change? I have signed up for a billing plan on Google Maps API.

Answer (score 1):

Google implemented a new pricing model and no longer allows for free geocoding.  If you have not signed up for a billing plan than your API key will not work.  See the documentation for more info: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-and-billing

Comment: The API key that I used was from a billing plan that I've signed up for on Google.