# Geocoding adresses with QGIS

Tags: qgis, geocoding, mmqgis

I want to transform about 750 addresses into geocoded points. I´ve tried the plugins MMQGIS (Geocode) and Geopunt4Qgis but none of the things I´ve tried worked. Maybe its because the addresses are German or the table is not formatted correctly before I export it to a CSV file.

the table looks like this:

[image: Table]

this is what I type in MMQGIS (the City is at the time a state, there is also no option for house numbers)

[image: picture]

this is the error I get:

[image]

this is in Geopunt4Qgis (there is an option for house numbers but I don´t have the postal code)

[image: picture 2]

Any solutions apart from QGIS are also welcome. Any ideas?

Comment: Google recently this year changed their geocoding services.  There is no longer free geocoding available from Google.  See this question for more info: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/294733/ssl-error-message-using-mmqgis-and-google-geocoding-api/295595#295595

Comment: there are not any other services?
in MMQGIS for example you can also use OpenStreetMap

Comment: You can use the Nomatim service in MMQGIS but it is not as robust as Google's geocoder.  Take a look at this question and maybe it will help you figure out if the problem is coming from how you scraped the data: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17912307/u-ufeff-in-python-string.